# Fastest way to find other node

Tags: c++, c, performance

I have a triangle class, with pointers to nodes (n0,n1,n2).  I also have a method that returns the 'other' node when passed two node pointers (a,b).  The current implementation is this:

```
if ( n0 == a && n1 == b )
{
    return n2;
}
else if ( n0 == b && n1 == a )
{
    return n2;
}
else if ( n1 == a && n2 == b )
{
    return n0;
}
else if ( n1 == b && n2 == a )
{
    return n0;
}
else if ( n0 == a && n2 == b )
{
    return n1;
}
else if ( n0 == b && n2 == a )
{
    return n1;
}
else
{
    assert( 0 );
}
return NULL;
```

Which works, but may not be best.  Upon profiling, my program actually spends measurable time in this routine, so it is worth some time to optimize.  However, I'm not very familiar with the optimizations the compiler will do anyway, so I'm not sure if this is redundant.

The nodes are in no particular order, so on average it will have to perform 3.5 of the compound comparisons.

An alternative approach would be this:

```
if ( n0 == a )
{
    if ( n1 == b )
    {
        return n2;
    }
    else if ( n2 == b )
    {
        return n1;
    }
    return NULL;
}
else if ( n1 == a )
{
    if ( n0 == b )
    {
        return n2;
    }
    else if ( n2 == b )
    {
        return n0;
    }
    return NULL;
}
else if ( n2 == a ) // Theoretically redundant.  Kept for safety.
{
    if ( n0 == b )
    {
        return n1;
    }
    else if ( n1 == b )
    {
        return n0;
    }
    return NULL;
}
return NULL;
```

Which works out to an average of 3.5 of the simple comparisons.  Will this be faster -- or will the compiler make them the same?

Is there a faster way?

I know I could eliminate the redundant if's.  In the first case, it reduces the average to 3.33 compound comparisons.  In the second case, it pulls the average down to 3.0 simple comparisons.

I could eliminate all the else's as every true block of code contains a return.  However, I really feel like the compiler should be smart enough to take care of any gain there itself.

Comment: "*Will this be faster*" - profile it and find out

Comment: It seems like your code works. For working code that is wanted to be optimised, there is an [appropriate site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Both of your code examples take into account the possibility that `a` and/or `b` may not be in the node at all. Is that a real possibility that must be supported? Or will `a` and `b` always be guaranteed to be in the node? If you can offer that guarantee, then you can knock out half of the comparisons.

Comment: @remy By asking before profiling, I was hoping to find understanding and insight, not just empirical evidence.  I believe we can guarantee this code never returns NULL.

Comment: @Fureeish Sorry for asking in the wrong place.

Comment: @user52485: "*this code never returns NULL*" - it will if `a` or `b` is not in the triangle that is being checked. That is why I asked about that.

Comment: No, I recognize that as a possible failure.  However in practice in my application, we don't actually check for NULL returned from this routine -- and the code has been working for ~12 years, so without doing a complete audit, it certainly seems like we never return NULL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anything XORed with itself will be zero, so if you're given two of the three, you can find the remaining one by just doing `n0 ^ n1 ^ n2 ^ a ^ b`. It's well deserving of an explanatory comment, but if speed matters, that's almost certainly your fastest alternative.

Comment: With appropriate casts, it seems to work `return (Node *) ((uintptr_t) n0 ^ (uintptr_t) n1 ^ (uintptr_t) n2 ^ (uintptr_t) a ^ (uintptr_t) b);`.  It does seem tough to beat.

Comment: Assuming both `a` and `b` are pointers to nodes inside of the triangle that is being checked.  If they are pointers to outside nodes, this approach fails.

Comment: Though this is the best answer to this question, it still leaves the slightly more general question unanswered -- do the compound conditionals take substantially more time than a simple conditional?  Is it worth manually expanding code like that to get down to simple conditionals where no check is repeated?